# Plotting a family of 2D curves of a surface of revolution using spherical coordinates

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to plot the family of curves $V = constant$  from the following surface of revolution expressed in spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ with $\phi = constant$:$$ V = \frac{2 r\sin\theta}{1+r^2}$$ where $0 \leq V \leq 1$ , $0 \leq r \lt \infty$ , $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ , ( so  $ 0 \leq \sin\theta \leq 1$ ) .

How can this be plotted so that $V$ is manipulated between 0 and 1, or plotted for $V$ in increments of 1/10 between 0 and 1 ?  I have not been able to do this with any Mathematica plotting functions. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: In Cartesian coordinates, $V = 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)$. So restricting to $\phi=0$, that is the $xz$-plane with $x>0$, we would get $V = 2x/(1+x^2+z^2)$. You want a 2-dim `ContourPlot` of that, in the $xz$ coordinate system?

Comment: @user293787  That is correct, although IMO it seems  better to use $\rho$ than $x$ because $x^2+y^2 = \rho^2$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After cogitating on the original answer, I believe that answer is incorrect. On page 112 of the book "Field Theory Handbook" by Moon and Spencer (second edition) is the toroidal coordinate system which has the equation relating the toroidal variable $\eta$ to the cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ as follows:$$x^2+y^2+z^2+a^2= 2a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\coth\eta$$ The curves $\eta= constant$ in the $\phi=constant$ plane are nested circles with $0\leqslant \eta \lt \infty$. $\quad$We have $$x^2+y^2=\rho^2$$Choosing  $a=1$ for use in Mathematica is equivalent to replacing $\rho$ and $z$ with $\frac{\rho}{a}$ and $\frac za$ ,
so equivalently we have$$ \coth\eta=\frac{\rho^2+z^2+1}{2\rho}$$where $(\rho,\phi,z)$ are the cylindrical coordinates with $\rho\geqslant0$ and $-\infty\lt z\lt+\infty$.$\quad$ In spherical coordinates this is $$\coth\eta=\frac{r^2+1}{2r\sin\theta}$$where $\rho = r\sin\theta$ and $\rho^2+z^2=r^2$.$\quad$We want to study the curves $\eta = constant$, so *any* function of $\eta$ will give the same curve shape, i.e. the nested circles of toroidal coordinates. If we choose the function $V$ such that $$V=\frac{2r\sin\theta}{r^2+1}$$ then $0\leqslant V\leqslant 1$, or in cylindrical coordinates$$V=\frac{2\rho}{\rho^2+z^2+1}$$This is the formula that is needed for plotting the originally stated problem, but the domain size of $\rho$ must be equal to the domain size of $z$ (like 8 for the ContourPlot below), otherwise the plotted curves will appear as nested ellipses instead of nested circles.  I believe that ContourPlot can only be used for 2D cartesian coordinates or cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,z)$ in the $\phi = constant$ plane because angles on one axis like $\theta$ and distances like $r$ on the other makes no sense.
[image: Plot of V]

Comment: You can always choose a new accepted answer if you want, including your own. Only the answer you choose last will have the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot [(2 r Sin[\[Theta]])/(1 + r^2), {r, 0, 10}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi},Contours -> Range[0, 10, .1], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: `r, θ` are spherical coordinates,not the Cartesian coordinate.

Comment: @cvgmt Where did you read about cartesian coordinates?

Comment: `{r, 0, 10}, {θ, 0, Pi}` indicate that your set `{r, θ}`  in Cartesion coordinates.

Comment: @cvgmt Sorry cannot follow. The question is described in spherical coordinates and the answer is given in the same coordinate space.

Comment: For example, when `φ = 0`, we need to map the contours in the domain `{r, 0, 10}, {θ, 0, Pi}` to 3D spaces by `{r,θ}|->{r Sin[θ], 0, r Cos[θ]}`

Comment: @cvgmt Never hearing/knowing anything about `cartesian coordinates` it's possible to give a complete  answer to the question!

Comment: Please note that `θ=Pi/2` is the equator of sphere etc. It mean that a line in Cartesian coordinate `{r,θ}` is a curve in space.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  Thanks so much Ulrich!  That's just what I expected it to look like from my rough sketch.  I believe your answer is correct.  Now all I have to do is fine tune all of the different plotting options.  You made it look so easy, and not necessary to introduce Cartesian Coordinates.

Comment: Dear @Bobster, if you are happy with this answer, please officially accept the answer by clicking on the chechmark. The checkmark should turn green once you do this. (And I think I am responsible for bringing up Cartesian coordinates, sorry for that.)

Comment: @user293787, thank you for telling me to click the checkmark.  I did not know about that.  I also thought the problem had to be restated in cartesian coordinates for Mathematica to plot the function, so I was surprised that it could be done in spherical coordinates (or any orthogonal coordinate system treated by Mathematica?)